# Customizing Ubuntu or any other Linux

Tags: ubuntu

For my personal project, I want to make a I-Pad (Tablet-PC) like device.
For that I want to customize Ubuntu (or any other OS that is easy to customize and free, Please suggest me).

Some example of what I want to customize are:
1) remove unnecessary services and Programs from OS.
2) Change the appearance of the dialog boxes/windows which appears.
3) Increase the size of close minimize etc. buttons.
4) Add new services.

How to do that? What path should I follow? How to do this?

I have very good experience in C/C++ and little experience on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

For customising the operating system, you do not have to code at all (at least for the above mentioned).

I suggest you learn more about the GNU/Linux system and how services are managed in it, the way themes are handled (depends on the desktop environment), et cetera.

Browse [TLDP](http://tldp.org/) for tutorials on most of the GNU/Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question It looks like you are trying to create your own Linux on top of you wants to run your own Code/Program.

For that LFS(Linux from scratch) will be the first choice for you. It is nicely documented and  at the end of compilation you will have working Linux into your Host system. However If you wants to create .iso image like Ubuntu, RHEL you can try Buildroot or Geexbox. With Buildroot and Geexbox compile at the end you will have .iso image which you can boot in qemu or in other  system and test it. You can also customize the packages available in Buildroot and Geexbox as per your requirement.

So As per me Buildroot is perfect choice for you to start.

Let me know if it works for you.